# Finding pairs of Amicable Numbers, up to 10000

Tags: c, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I have this program to find pairs of [amicable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amicable_numbers) in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("|---------- PROGRAM FOR AMICABLE NUMBERS.----------|");
    int num1,num2,sum=0;
    for(num1=1; num1<=10000; num1++)
    {
        for(num2=1; num2<=10000; num2++)
            {
                if ((num1==sum_of_divisors(num2)) && (num2==sum_of_divisors(num1)) && num1!=num2)
                {
                    printf("\n%d\t\t%d", num1,num2);
                }
            }
    }
    return 0;
}

int sum_of_divisors(int n)
{
    int sum=0,i;
    for(i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
         if(n%i==0)
         {
              sum=sum+i;
         }         
    }   
    return sum;
}
```

I'd like to improve the performance - it's taking around 10 minutes to find even the first 4 pairs.

Comment: You'd get a slight improvement in readability if you used C99 features such as declaring the loop index variables inside the init-statements of the `for` statements.

Comment: Since nobody mentioned it yet: *format your source code consistently* (indentation, spacing around operators, etc.). Also, don’t waste vertical space: put opening braces on the preceding line. This particular advice might be somewhat controversial but I maintain it objectively improves readability.

Comment: This question is about [Project Euler, Problem 21](https://projecteuler.net/problem=21).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
    printf("|---------- PROGRAM FOR AMICABLE NUMBERS.----------|");
```

This kind of banner message makes it harder to use the output of your program in a pipeline.  I'd suggest removing it (the user has chosen to run it; trust them to know what they're doing!).

---

```
    int num1,num2,sum=0;
```

What's `sum` for?  It doesn't seem to be used.

---

```
    for(num1=1; num1<=10000; num1++)
```

Where does the magic value `10000` come from?  It should be a named constant (or, better, specifiable as a command-line argument).

---

```
        for(num2=1; num2<=10000; num2++)
```

Do we really need to consider every pair in both directions?  We could simply iterate while `num2 < num1` (which also saves ourselves a comparison later).  But see below why this loop isn't needed at all.

---

```
                if ((num1==sum_of_divisors(num2))
```

There's no prototype visible for `sum_of_divisors()` - enable the relevant compiler warnings and provide the prototype (e.g. by moving the definition ahead of `main()`).

---

```
        for(num2=1; num2<=10000; num2++)
            {
                if ((num1==sum_of_divisors(num2))
                    && (num2==sum_of_divisors(num1))
                    && num1!=num2)
```

In the inner loop, `sum_of_divisors(num1)` is a constant, so we could save it in the outer loop, and make that the first comparison (so that short-circuit `&&` will then evaluate `sum_of_divisors(num2)` just once).  Then observe that we have a loop which tests whether its index is equal to a particular value - that means that we replace the inner loop with a single test:

```
    for (num1 = 1;  num1 <= 10000;  num1++) {
         num2 = sum_of_divisors(num1);
         if (num1 < num2 && sum_of_divisors(num2) == num1) {
             /* we found a pair */
         }
    }
```

The `num2 < num1` test there saves us re-finding pairs we've already seen.  `num2 > num1` would also work, of course - I chose this version so that we print each pair lowest-first, as that seems to be the convention.

---

```
                    printf("\n%d\t\t%d", num1,num2);
```

It's better to consistently end your output with newline, rather than beginning with newline.  This works better in programs that might emit errors or other diagnostics, and plays nicely with line-buffered output such as interactive terminals (where the newline causes a flush).

---

```
    for(i=1; i<n; i++) if(n%i==0) sum += i;
```

This is a really inefficient way to accumulate factors.  You can reduce it to the range (1, √n) with `sum += i + n/i` (adjusted a little to avoid double-counting `√n` when `n` is square); it may be better instead to generate all the prime factors and use those to generate the composite factors.

---

After making the above improvements, I found the runtime was below my measurement threshold.  Increasing the limit to 1 million gives a runtime of about 2 seconds - that might be acceptable; if not, the problem parallelizes well (other than outputting the results).

---

## Modified version

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if USE_LONG_TYPE
typedef unsigned long Number;
#define FMT "%lu"
#else
typedef unsigned int Number;
#define FMT "%u"
#endif

static const Number MAX_VALUE = 1000000;


Number sum_of_factors(Number n)
{
    Number sum = 1;
    Number i = 2;
    for (;  i < n/i;  ++i) {
        if (n/i*i == n) {
            sum += i + n/i;
        }
    }
    if (i*i == n)
        sum += i; /* add square root only once */
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    //#pragma omp parallel for
    for (Number num1 = 1;  num1 <= MAX_VALUE;  ++num1) {
        Number num2 = sum_of_factors(num1);
        if (num2 > num1 && num1 == sum_of_factors(num2)) {
            printf(FMT "\t\t" FMT "\n", num1, num2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that a pair (n, n) is skipped because of the test num2 > num1 ? (I would have written num2 >= num1 or handled equality as a special case)

Comment: `i*i < n` is a problem on overflow, E.g. a _long_ loop with 32-bit `unsigned` and `n == 4294967291`, a large prime.  Safe alternative `i < n/i`

Comment: The 2nd `i*i == n` is tricker to avoid OF.  I think `if (n%i == 0)` should work.

Comment: @Josay: "Is it possible that a pair (_n_, _n_) is skipped...?"  Such an (_n_, _n_) is not a "pair", it's a single number! Such a number _n_ (whose sum-of-divisors is equal to the number _n_ itself) is called "[perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number)." Perfect numbers are (by definition) not amicable numbers, so it's correct to skip them.

Comment: Oh indeed, I didn't notice these cases were filtered out on the original vide add well. Thanks for the reply

Comment: You don't actually say in your text  that there is no need to iterate over all 10,000 possible values of num2 in order to find the one which is equal to the sum of factors of num1 - we can just calculate it (and this will probably make the program run ~10,000 times faster).

Comment: I'm gonna guess that the "magic number 10,000" comes from the problem being from project Euler. https://projecteuler.net/problem=21

Comment: Yes @chux, there is a risk of overflow with `i*i`.  It may well be worth converting the square root back to integer to avoid that.  The other option would be to disallow `n` greater than `INT_MAX`-2×√`INT_MAX`-`1` (substitute `LONG_MAX` as appropriate).  Overflow is not a problem with `i*i == n`, because we're using unsigned types, and if overflow occurs there, `n` cannot be square, and we function correctly.

Comment: @chux, I've updated my version to avoid the overflow in the loop constraint.  As a bonus, it increases the speed, because we can re-use the `n/i` in the divisibility test (surprisingly, I got an almost 2× speedup, despite `n/i` and `n%i` being results of the same division - I thought that modern x86 processors produced quotient and remainder together?  Maybe GCC doesn't spot the connection?).

Comment: too terse: Yes it was - I missed it.  I think part of the problem is that it was not in the section  labelled `for(num2=1; num2<=10000; num2++)` which is where I was expecting it.  It's worth pointing out that we only need to consider `num2 < num1` (or `>`, obviously doesn't matter) because that comment can apply in other cases too.

Comment: @TobySpeight True about [because we're using unsigned types](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/184646/finding-pair-of-amicable-numbers-under-10000-in-c-taking-too-long/184655?noredirect=1#comment352109_184655).  The `if (n%i == 0) sum += i;` may be useful with `typedef int Number`.  Yes many compilers compute `a/b ... a%b` as a common operation.

Comment: Zero/one corner cases: Suggest `Number sum = n > 1;` even though `sum_of_factors(0)` not used in this code.   Not sure if `sum_of_factors(1)` messes up other code.

Comment: Oh, that's much clearer.  Excellent tutorial now.

Comment: You are computing `sum_of_factor` multiple times with the same value I think. Memoization might help optimize that away.

Comment: Yes, Dancrumb's answer suggested memoizing the `sum_of_factor()` results.  I see no need to repeat that here.

Answer (score 22):

> ```
>     for(num1=1; num1<=10000; num1++)
>     {
>         for(num2=1; num2<=10000; num2++)
>             {
>                 if (... && (num2==sum_of_divisors(num1)) && ...)
> ```

There's an obvious optimisation here which will give you roughly a 10000 times speedup...

---

> ```
> int sum_of_divisors(int n)
> {
>     int sum=0,i;
>     for(i=1; i<n; i++)
>     {
>          if(n%i==0)
>          {
>               sum=sum+i;
> ```

This is not the fastest way to calculate it.

Optimisation 1: only loop up to `i*i <= n` and use the fact that if `n / i = j` then `n / j = i`.

Optimisation 2: what is the formula for the sum of divisors given the prime factorisation? How can you find the prime factorisation efficiently?

Optimisation 3: you don't actually want the sum of divisors of one number, but of all of them up to `N`. How can you adapt the sieve of Eratosthenes to calculate the sum of divisors of all numbers up to `N` efficiently?

Comment: Do you mean  `i <= n/2`? Because `i*i <= n` is giving wrong results. Suppose `n=10` then loop will stop at `i=4` but `5` is a factor of `10`.

Comment: That sentence contains two halves linked by *and*. If you implement the first half and not the second half, things will go wrong.

Comment: Will `i <= n/2` be better than what you suggested ? Because it did shortened time.

Comment: Only for very small `n`. If the multiplication is too slow, you could calculate`sqrt(n)` before the loop instead.

Comment: "which will give you roughly a 10000 times speedup..." of half the work, leading to a 2 times speedup of the program as a whole.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, if you think that was hinting at merely pulling `sum_of_divisors(num1)` out of the loop then you have seriously missed the point, which is that the inner loop does not need to be a loop at all.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, yes I missed that. It's obvious once you see it. :)

Comment: How many tons of gold for a helpful answer for the 2nd part of `Optimisation 2`?

Comment: I saw your "Optimization 3" hint the other day and it caused me to scratch my head. I finally had the AH-HA moment. Well done!

Answer (score 13):

Try the following (MUCH faster):

```
int num, num2, num3;
for (num1 = 1; num1<=10000; num1++)
{
    num2 = sum_of_divisors(num1);
    if (num1 < num2)    /* at least one of any amicable pair is larger */
    {
        num3 = sum_of_divisors(num2);
        if (num3 == num1)    /* FOUND AN AMICABLE PAIR! */
            ... (record the pair) ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That's super fast. Even calculated till 8th pair in under 5 seconds.

Comment: Upvoting because you were the first one to write the code for this solution. It was only hinted by Peter Taylor, and Toby Speight only wrote it in a later edit.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] it to explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that everyone can learn from your thought process.

Comment: @TobySpeight Bearing in mind it isn't completely agreed upon by all, there is a justification, albeit short, but it does somewhat "_[answer the question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1479/120114)_" (though it doesn't give concrete measurements of *how* "MUCH faster" it is)

Comment: It would also benefit from a brief summary of *why* it's faster, too.

Answer (score 8):

```
for(num1=1; num1<=10000; num1++)
{
    for(num2=1; num2<=10000; num2++)
        {
            if ((num1==sum_of_divisors(num2)) && (num2==sum_of_divisors(num1)) && num1!=num2)
```

To add a minor note that the other 2 answers didn't mention:

You're calling sum_of_divisors() about 20000x as many times as you should be.

You're calling it many times with the same input value and it's a fairly expensive function.

If you calculate sum_of_divisors() for the numbers 1 to 10000 once, right at the beginning of your program and store the output in an array and look at that whenever you need the value then you won't end up repeating the same work ~10,000x as many times as you need to and you can instead just do it once.

Comment: Actually everything there is in my answer, just in the form of hints.

Comment: Yes I got that when Peter mentioned _10000 times speedup_. Thanks for explaining though. Will be helpful for future viewers.

Comment: @PeterTaylor your hint made me think of some alternative approaches, I wasn't sure whether you were referring to precomputation or to a few of the other possible optimizations like limiting direction of comparison and/or moving one of the calls into a higher loop or cutting out pairs that can never be amicable.

Comment: This observation is also in my answer; admittedly it's easily missed: "*you can reduce the second loop to a single test*".

Answer (score 5):

One thing to consider is the `sum_of_divisors` function.

It is a pure function, meaning that its return value depends only on the input parameter `i`.

In addition, it is called 100,000,000 times, but with only values 1 to 1,000,000.

It is ripe for `memoization`. This basically means that, when the function is called, the return value is cached with the input parameter being the key. Subsequent calls with the same input parameter just return the cached value.

Thus,

```
int sum_of_divisors(int n)
{
    int sum=0,i;
    for(i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
         if(n%i==0)
         {
              sum=sum+i;
         }         
    }   
    return sum;
}
```

becomes

```
int sums[1000000];
int sum_of_divisors(int n)
{
    if(sums[n]) {
       return sums[n];
    }
    int sum=0,i;
    for(i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
         if(n%i==0)
         {
              sum=sum+i;
         }         
    }   
    sums[n] = sum;
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Good idea. Make the array static inside the function though.

Comment: Further clarification: `if (sums[n]) {` for unknown `n`s works, because `int[]`array elements get initialized with `0` and `0` is equivalent to `false` in this case.

Comment: Memoization is a good idea, yet this `sum_of_divisors()` is O(n) and should be O(sqrt(n)).  That O() change has a much bigger impact.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is one of the best solutions to your problem. It works in around 1 second and finds all pairs between 1 and 20 millions.

First, we need to calculate the smallest divisor of each number with this method: [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://e-maxx-eng.appspot.com/algebra/prime-sieve-linear.html).

Then we use that sigma(n) - sum of all divisors of n is [Multiplicative function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function). For each number i  we know its smallest divisor - p. Find greatest k that i is divisible by p^k. Now, sigma(i) is sigma(p^k) * sigma(i / p^k)

Now, we can calculate sum of proper divisors of each number. sum_proper[i] = sigma[i] - i.

Finally, let's iterate over i and check whether sigma[sigma[i]] = i and print the answer.

## The code

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int N = 20000000;
const int CNT_PRIMES = N; // upper bound on number of primes within range from 1 to N

int main()
{
    int smallest_divisor[N];
    int sigma[N];
    int sum_proper[N];
    int primes[CNT_PRIMES];
    int curcnt = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < N; ++i)
        smallest_divisor[i] = i;
    for (int i = 2; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (smallest_divisor[i] == i)
            primes[curcnt++] = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < curcnt && primes[j] <= smallest_divisor[i] && primes[j] * i < N; ++j)
            smallest_divisor[primes[j] * i] = primes[j];
    }
    sigma[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < N; ++i)
    {
        int cur = i;
        int p = smallest_divisor[i];
        int k = 0;
        while (cur % p == 0)
            cur /= p, ++k;
        int pk = i / cur;
        sigma[i] = (pk * p - 1) / (p - 1); // sigma(p^k) = 1 + p + ... + p^k = (p^(k+1) - 1) / (p - 1)
        sigma[i] *= sigma[cur];
        sum_proper[i] = sigma[i] - i;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i < N; ++i)
    {
        int j = sum_proper[i];
        if (j < N && j > i && sum_proper[j] == i)
            printf("%d\t\t%d\n", i, j);
    }
}
```

<kbd>**[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/JJSivZ)**</kbd>

Comment: I gave it a quick check and it's throwing too many exceptions. Mostly `variably modified smallest_divisor at file scope`. Same for other variables declared outside main.

Comment: @Rahul what is your compilation arguments? I compiled it with gcc a.cpp -o a -O2

Comment: I am compiling within Dev C++ 5.4.2 IDE.

Comment: @Rahul, try to move all global variables to the main maybe

Comment: What [insight](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) does this provide about the code in the question?

Comment: @greybeard Well, the fact that the solution is very far from optimal, so Rahul should optimize it or use another one. Very good optimization is to pre-calculate sum_of_divisors for each number. Another optimization is to calculate it in O(1) instead of O(sqrt(n)). If we apply this two optimizations we will get this code exclusive of variable names.

Comment: A valid observation about the code to review is that it uses brute force, bound to exceed the time limit of any self-respecting challenge. While the approach above is excellent, its presentation is not - if interested in peer views, present it as a question on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: (There *is* a reason why your answer got this comment while others' didn't: see [First Posts review queue](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to say something about the original code (you might want to hoist your comment to greybeard into the answer, as a starting point).

Comment: @Rahul You're compiling C code with a compiler for a different language. Of course it does not work as expected.

Comment: @pipe: Dev C++ works both for C and C++. It has MinGW compiler.

Comment: `const int N = 20000000; 
int smallest_divisor[N];`--> invalid C code.  Global arrays need a _constant_ size.  `N` is not a _constant_, but a `const` object.

Comment: @chux fixed by moving arrays to the main

Answer (score 0):

This is actually [Project Euler's problem 21](https://projecteuler.net/problem=21).

If you want pure performance, just get rid of the divisions altogether.

I don't know C well enough to actually review the code, but I wrote an efficient solution for Java a few years back, and wanted to share it. The algorithm is rather simple and requires only some changes in the way of thinking about what is a divisor. You'll see, I'm basically only using the addition (except at one time, for... doubling).

```java
// Note: this is Java, not C
public static int projectEuler21(final int limit) {

  int[] sumOfDivisors = new int[limit];
  int sum = 0;

  // For each number below the limit
  for (int number = 1; number < limit; number++) {

    // Add it as divisor to each of its multiples
    for (int multiple = number * 2; multiple < limit; multiple += number) {
      sumOfDivisors[multiple] += number;
    }

    // sum both number and sumOfDivisors[number] if they're amicable, but only if number is the larger of the pair
    if (sumOfDivisors[number] < number && number == sumOfDivisors[sumOfDivisors[number]]) {
      sum += number + sumOfDivisors[number];
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

The code above is performing extremely well as [it runs in the order of 2 or 3 milliseconds](https://tio.run/##dZNdb9owFIbv9yuOKtGFQSGhV23KRbUPaZO2TuvuUDQ5iUPNHDuyHSo08dvZ8UeSlgIKkPg855zX73E2ZEuuZEPFpvx7c2janLMCCk60hu@ECfj3DiCsakMM/m0lK6HGWPRoFBPrVQZErfXYoQBMGOCsZgaW8FUYuqZqtiW8pQ9VZLlVnI1TR3Ip1mBYTZF83GlD65kgQv7GlSggtpiiuuW2WqPkhhbmc8upWiSRaxK4c1XgyoU8FKKyNbMGhZsquvjpS4KrCYtkJC7GZ@FfTsgtjErEpkHXedwquMXQaHZdQa1djtM5h@RPHMf2W7r0/QFgPocf0mCCeWIa8PqGg5mCkAY@vhmBteXIjYoJwgfz7TQ6B3FAuq0fqk9sy7RUGo0S9NlFHJsNXiOH0Tj1uajpi1RASfEEoq1ztCinXD6jRurbOKxCJrLZgVlCknb3d57rnieTXpgrf1@WgCeFaCi9ODDS95MVBjTUaDFrONUhp@/VBexmfKsPsEiH5b5xvzLpyO6k2s8rY1Ydmw1wGtD9C9XWpVya3hQiyqNCPpABq6xXu/eKAqlZQXJOp5C3BqTgOxsNFXDezlN8QfBJuixoCFOhKZLR6Q53XYnLy97/5ZGak5nZkQ3DlmFyejeDFcOvoqZVwvL@IO8PhwTPdfwf). It runs between 5 and 6 seconds if you change the limit to 20,000,000.

Comment: The Project Euler specification is slightly different, although it does require finding amicable pairs.  The question code simply _prints_ the pairs, but PE is asking for the _sum_ of all the amicable numbers in a range.  Always check the specification before starting to code!

Comment: @TobySpeight The request was about speed improvement, it beats any of the other answers in terms of performance, even your algorithm, but whatever... I guess there's a reason why Stack Overflow and friends are on the decline.

Comment: Sure, just pointing out that you misread the question code, according to your first sentence.  The other suggestions are great.